# Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't load unity

Tags: boot, unity, compiz, launcher, 15.10

After formatting from windows7 I installed ubuntu 15.10 from a usb drive. Although everything seems to be installed correctly after booting all I see is my wallpaper. Unity, no launcher, no dash appears. I have tried to Install compizconfig-settings-manager but when I switch back to the graphical server I see nothing. Any ideas oh what I am doing wrong?